# How to detect if an integer is passed to the @PathVaraible annotation in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to validate that an integer value has been passed to the @PathVariable annotation.  I have set up the following configuration file:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration {

@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
}
```

And then I have the following in my Controller

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class UserController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{userID}", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public ResponseEntity<User> get(
  @PathVariable @NumberFormat(style = Style.NUMBER) int id)  {
  ///Code here
}
```

What annotation can I use to detect if an integer value has been passed? I have tested the @Min and @Range annotations and they work correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a solution on how to validate the path variable 
[here](https://it.asm0dey.ru/2016/10/09/validation-of-pathvariable-in-spring-mvc/)
.Using the following:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "\\d{9}", message = "Bank shoud be identified by exactly 9 digits")
```